# Is there a way to listen for when [PFUser currentUser] changes to a different user?

Tags: ios, authentication, parse-platform

Is there any sort of notification that gets posted, method of key-value observing, etc. that would allow me to listen for when the current user changes? The change could be due to logging out, signing up, logging in, etc. Right now, I have to carefully post a notification each time the current user could change in my code, so it would be much nicer to have a guaranteed notification that I wouldn't have to think about.

Comment: Nothing within the Parse SDK. But can be done with custom code

Comment: How would you do it with custom code?

Comment: It would have to be built ground up. Create columns or pointers/relations in your parse backend that you can set values or BOOL to when their status changes (with a session token on Parse Cloud or otherwise) and apply accordingly. Then perform your notification based on that. It can be code heavy